# Python changing command line argument with a script

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I'm new to coding so this "obvious" action isn't really obvious to me. I've read on W3schools.com and other forums on the web about my problem but can't figure if I'm looking at the wrong solution or just can't do it.

I was able to run this python script from that site https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/11/12/yolo-object-detection-with-opencv/

It basically opens a command-line terminal which in you do insert argument and the script performs an object detection action.
What I want to do, is creating a script that automatically gets the image input path and then pastes it in the command line.

```py
import os

imageFile = test1
os.system("python yolo.py --image {}.jpg --yolo yolo-coco").format(imageFile)
```

Furthermore, I'm asking myself how to get rid of the command line argument to paste arguments. Is there any way to accomplish this by directly putting the image's path in the base script?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Is the script "Click here to download the source code to this post?"

Comment: yes. I don't know if i can paste it here...